# Sort Rows in R by certain characteristic

Tags: r, sorting

I've read a few questions that have been answered and are similar, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to apply it to my question. I have a data frame like this (some entries are blank, the number of columns are determined by the pronunciation guide of a word)

```
5   SUPERNATURALISM   S UW2   P ER0   N AE1  CH ER0 AH0   L IH2   Z AH0   M
6         ESTABLISH IH0   S   T AE1   B   L IH0  SH  
7            FABRIC   F AE1   B   R IH0   K 
1504         AMTRAK AE1   M   T   R AE0   K
```

I'd basically like to be able to sort the table according to the number of syllables, and that's easily visible by the number of times you see a number (0,1 or 2) in each row (the 0,1,or 2 indicates the stress placed on the vowels. The consonants like S, P, and so on, don't come attached with a number)

For example, Row 7 and 1504 both have 2 syllables because there are 2 numbers in each row (although in different columns), so I'd like them to be together.

In the end, I'd just like to sort it so out of the 4 rows I showed, the order should be 7,1504,6,5

Does anyone know the code I should write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to process the data first, probably `regex` is the way to go. Here is a solution (I will use the package `stringr`):

```
## your data
df <- read.table(text=
"5   SUPERNATURALISM   S UW2   P ER0   N AE1  CH ER0 AH0   L IH2   Z AH0   M
6         ESTABLISH IH0   S   T AE1   B   L IH0  SH  
7            FABRIC   F AE1   B   R IH0   K 
1504         AMTRAK AE1   M   T   R AE0   K                                  ",
                   fill=TRUE,
                   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Manipulating to extract numbers and count:

```
library(stringr)
text <- apply(df[,3:16], 1,paste, collapse="")
numbers <- str_extract_all(text, "\\d+")
df$syllables <- sapply(numbers, length)
```

Order:

```
df <- df[order(df$syllables),]
df
    V1              V2  V3  V4 V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 syllables
3    7          FABRIC   F AE1  B   R IH0   K                                         2
4 1504          AMTRAK AE1   M  T   R AE0   K                                         2
2    6       ESTABLISH IH0   S  T AE1   B   L IH0  SH                                 3
1    5 SUPERNATURALISM   S UW2  P ER0   N AE1  CH ER0 AH0   L IH2   Z AH0   M         7
```

Comment: Hey, I just saw your solution and I think it's exactly what I'm looking for! Let me try it out with a few data sets, and then I can come back and confirm, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can extract digit from each line and order them according to the number of digits(length of the list)

```
library(stringr)
## read lines
ll <- readLines(textConnection('5   SUPERNATURALISM   S UW2   P ER0   N AE1  CH ER0 AH0   L IH2   Z AH0   M
6         ESTABLISH IH0   S   T AE1   B   L IH0  SH  
7            FABRIC   F AE1   B   R IH0   K 
1504         AMTRAK AE1   M   T   R AE0   K '))
## extract digit , remove the first one and order 
ord <- order(sapply(str_extract_all(ll,'\\d+'),function(x)length(x[-1])))
## get the result
ll[ord]

[1] "7            FABRIC   F AE1   B   R IH0   K "                               
[2] "1504         AMTRAK AE1   M   T   R AE0   K "                               
[3] "6         ESTABLISH IH0   S   T AE1   B   L IH0  SH  "                      
[4] "5   SUPERNATURALISM   S UW2   P ER0   N AE1  CH ER0 AH0   L IH2   Z AH0   M"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply, I'm still sort of new to R, and when I replace "ll" in your second command with my matrix/data frame, I get "Error: String must be an atomic vector". Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using base and positive look-behind regex (using @agstudy's data):

```
len = unlist(lapply(ll, function(x) 
         length(gregexpr("(?<=[A-Za-z])[0-2]", x, perl=TRUE)[[1L]])))
ll[order(len)]
```

The regex `(?<=[A-Za-z])[0-2]` basically means if there's a number between 0-2 and it's previous character is any of the alphabets, then there's a match. `perl=TRUE` is required for matching with look-ahead and look-behind regexps as it requires PCRE.

We loop through `ll` using this regex. `gregexpr` returns a list with it's first index returning the position of matches. So, we extract it using `length(.)` and then use `order` to rearrange `ll`.

HTH